# Dependency hell in NestJS/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I build `NestJS` projecct with many modules and recently I got lost in them a bit, My last thing which I'm doing was added `QueueService` to my `ProjectService` and `ProjectModule`, but after launch whole app, the compiler throw me this:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QueueService (UtilsService, UserService, Connection, ?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [3] is available in the ProjectModule context.
```

The argument at the index[3] at `QueueService` is `ProjectService`, so why they want from me to import `ProjectModule/ProjectService` into my `ProjectModule`? :P

here is my all code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
    constructor(
        private conn: Connection,
        private utilsService: UtilsService,
        private userService: UserService,
        private notificationService: NotificationsService,
        private queueService: QueueService 
    ) { }
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt'})
  ],
  providers: [ProjectService, UtilsService, UserService, NotificationsService, QueueService ],
  controllers: [ProjectController],
  exports: [ProjectService]
})
export class ProjectModule {}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class QueueService {
    constructor(
        readonly conn: Connection,
        readonly utilsService: UtilsService,
        readonly userService: UserService,
        readonly projectService: ProjectService
    ){}
}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt'})],
  providers: [QueueService , UtilsService, UserService, NotificationsService, ProjectService],
  controllers: [QueueController ],
  exports: [PassportModule]
})
export class QueueModule {}
```

AppModule

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ...,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService
    }),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt'}),
    JwtModule.register({
        secret: 'secretKey'
    }),
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    ...,
    ...,
    QueueModule,
    ...,
    ...,
    ProjectModule,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
  ],
  controllers: [..., ..., ..., ..., ...],
  providers: [ ..., ..., ..., ..., ...,ProjectService, ..., ..., QueueService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

thanks for any help, I stuck here for 3-4h and I do not know what can I do more :(

////////////////////////////////////

Comment: looks like you need to import the `ProjectModule` into `QueueModule`. Did you tried this? (just put `ProjectModule` in `imports` array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, lots to unpack here. So you've got [circular dependencies](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) between your services and you *should* have circular dependencies between your modules. What's happening right now is that you're creating two instances of `QueueService` and two instances of `ProjectService`. However, because these services depend on each other, there isn't a way for Nest to properly instantiate them (at least how you have it currently).

So, the quick and easy fix here, if you want two of each, is to add the proper `forwardRef` for the circularly dependent classes.

#### QueueService

```js
@Injectable()
export class QueueService {
    constructor(
        readonly conn: Connection,
        readonly utilsService: UtilsService,
        readonly userService: UserService,
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => ProjectService))
        readonly projectService: ProjectService
    ){}
}
```

#### ProjectService

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
    constructor(
        private conn: Connection,
        private utilsService: UtilsService,
        private userService: UserService,
        private notificationService: NotificationsService,
        @Inject(forwardref(() => QueueService))
        private queueService: QueueService 
    ) { }
```

Now if that's all you want, great, feel free to stop reading here and go about your business.

---

So what should be happening? If you want true singletons of each service (services only created once) you should be sharing the providers via the modules they belong to and importing the module, not creating a new `provider` value. As your `ProjectModule` and `QueueModule` are circularly dependent, you'll need to once again use `forwardRef`. The services above are still valid, so I won't worry about re-writing those, but your modules should look like below:

#### QueueModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    forwardRef(() => ProjectModule),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt'})],
  providers: [QueueService , UtilsService, UserService, NotificationsService],
  controllers: [QueueController ],
  exports: [PassportModule, QueueService]
})
export class QueueModule {}
```

#### ProjectModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    forwardref(() => QueueModule),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt'})
  ],
  providers: [ProjectService, UtilsService, UserService, NotificationsService ],
  controllers: [ProjectController],
  exports: [ProjectService]
})
export class ProjectModule {}
```

You should absolutely look into your `UtilsModule`, `NotificationsModule`, and `UserModule` to clean up their exports, and re-use the module instead of new provider instances as well.